# Argument Error in Elixir when trying to access a list by index with list[i]

Tags: elixir, argument-error

Please Help anyone! I am trying to print the list using for loop but i am getting this error, I am very new to elixir and din't konw how to solve this

```elixir
defmodule Todos do
 def matrix_of_sum do
   [
     [21 ,"na", "na", "na", 12],
     ["na", "na", 12, "na", "na"],
     ["na", "na", "na", "na", "na"],
     [17, "na", "na", "na", "na"],
     ["na", 22, "na", "na", "na"]
   ]
 end
# print the rows and colums off the tuple in elixir
 def print_list do
  for i <- 0..4 do
      for j <- 0..4 do
          if matrix_of_sum[i][j] != "na" do
              IO.puts matrix_of_sum[i][j]
          end
      end
   end
  end
 end
```

#Error

```elixir
** (ArgumentError) the Access calls for keywords expect the key to be an atom, got: 0
(elixir 1.14.0) lib/access.ex:313: Access.get/3
(todos 0.1.0) lib/todos.ex:15: anonymous fn/3 in Todos.print_list/0
(elixir 1.14.0) lib/enum.ex:4299: Enum.reduce_range/5
(todos 0.1.0) lib/todos.ex:14: anonymous fn/2 in Todos.print_list/0
(elixir 1.14.0) lib/enum.ex:4299: Enum.reduce_range/5
(todos 0.1.0) lib/todos.ex:13: Todos.print_list/0
iex:24: (file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Elixir, lists cannot be accessed by `list[index]` using the [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html) behaviour.

You could use [`Enum.at/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#at/2), like:

```elixir
matrix_of_sum |> Enum.at(i) |> Enum.at(j)
```

But this would be inefficient: Elixir [lists](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html#linked-lists) are linked lists and accessing by index has a linear cost.

What you want instead is to directly use [`for`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) directly on the lists:

```elixir
for row <- matrix_of_sum, cell <- row do
  if cell != "na" do
    IO.puts(cell)
  end
end
```

The reason why the error is a bit confusing is because `Access` tries to read the list as a [keyword list](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html#keyword-lists): it would then need `i` to be an atom key, not an integer.

Comment: Thankyou so much @sabiwara, I was stuck in  this from yesterday totally frustrated.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to store the value in a new list without the nil values

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer without seeing what you try to accomplish, but  [`Enum.filtler/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) or [`Enum.reject/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reject/2) can help return a new filtered list from a list. Also, `for` can also filter as pointed out by Adam.

Comment: A general advice if you come from an imperative language background is to try to think less about loops and accessing by index (good with arrays, terrible with linked lists), and to think more in terms of data transformation. Getting familiar with the `Enum` module and browsing its doc to find solutions is key. And whenever you need a swiss-army knife, you can use [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3-reduce-as-a-building-block) like a loop, but there is a gotcha: you must build lists using prepends + a final reverse, not appends.