# iterating 2D array in Elixir

Tags: multidimensional-array, elixir, elixir-mix

I am new to Elixir language and I am having some issues while writing a piece of code.

What I am given is a 2D array like

```
list1 = [
           [1 ,2,3,4,"nil"],
           [6,7,8,9,10,],
           [11,"nil",13,"nil",15],
           [16,17,"nil",19,20] ]
```

Now, what I've to do is to get all the elements that have values between 10 and 20, so what I'm doing is:

```
final_list = []
Enum.each(list1, fn row ->   
Enum.each(row, &(if (&1 >= 10 and &1 <= 99) do final_list = final_list ++ &1 end)) 
end
)
```

Doing this, I'm expecting that I'll get my list of numbers in final_list but I'm getting blank final list with a warning like:

```
warning: variable "final_list" is unused (there is a variable with the same name in the context, use the pin operator (^) to match on it or prefix this variable with underscore if it is not meant to be used)
  iex:5

:ok
```

and upon printing final_list, it is not updated.

When I try to check whether my code is working properly or not, using IO.puts as:

```
iex(5)> Enum.each(list1, fn row ->                                              ...(5)> Enum.each(row, &(if (&1 >= 10 and &1 <= 99) do IO.puts(final_list ++ &1) end))     
...(5)> end
...(5)> )
```

The Output is:

10

```
11
13
15
16
17
19
20
:ok
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong here? Shouldn't it add the elements to the `final_list`?
If this is wrong ( probably it is), what should be the possible solution to this?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://elixirforum.com/t/itertating-a-2d-matrix/50849

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916667/argument-error-in-elixir-when-trying-to-access-a-list-by-index-with-listi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73957249/enum-filter-3-is-undefined-or-private

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Adam's comments, this is a FAQ and the important thing is the message "warning: variable "final_list" is unused (there is a variable with the same name in the context, use the pin operator (^) to match on it or prefix this variable with underscore if it is not meant to be used)" This message actually indicates a very serious problem.

It tells you that the assignment "final_list = final_list ++ &1" is useless since it just creates a *local* variable, hiding the external one. Elixir variables are not mutable so you need to reorganize seriously your code.

Comment: This is kinda misleading, because [tag:elixir] variables are rebindable, and `final_list = final_list ++ &1` would have made a total sense if it was not done inside another scope. That said, the issue here is scoping, not mutability.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is

```
final_list = 
  for sublist <- list1,
      n <- sublist,
      is_number(n),
      n in 10..20,
      do: n
```

Note that every time you write `final_list = ...`, you actually declare a new variable with the same name, so the `final_list` you declared inside your anonymous function is not the `final_list` outside the anonymous function.